# C# - Microsoft sql database | Can't add new user on my e-contact app

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio-2019

I tried to make an e-contact app with C# on Visual Studio 2019 connected to a Miscrosoft SQL database (local) following a youtube tutorial.

The app is not complete yet, anyway the `btnAdd` should work, but it doesn't add the user and the return of the method (Insert).

It always returns `false` - Can anyone help me?

```
private void BntAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //Get the value from the imput fields
    c.Nome = txtBoxName.Text;
    c.Cognome = txtBoxSurname.Text;
    c.Telefono1= txtBoxPhone1.Text;
    c.Telefono = txtBoxPhone.Text;
    c.Email = txtBoxEmail.Text;

    //Inserting Data into Database uing the method we created is previous episode
    bool success = c.Insert(c);
    if (success == true)
    {
        //Successfully Inserted
        MessageBox.Show("New contact added!");
        //Call the clear Method Here
        Clear();
    }
    else
    {
        //Failed to add Contact
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR!)");
    }
    //load Data on Data GRidview
    DataTable dt = c.Select();
    dgvRubrica.DataSource = dt;
}

public void Clear()
{
    txtBoxName.Text = "";
    txtBoxSurname.Text = "";
    txtBoxPhone1.Text = "";
    txtBoxPhone.Text = "";
    txtBoxEmail.Text = "";
}
```

---

```
public bool Insert (rubricaClass c) {
    bool isSuccess = false;

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myconnstrng);
    try
    {
        string sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_Rubrica (Nome, Cognome, Telefono1, Telefono, Email) VALUES (@Nome, @Cognome, @Telefono1, @Telefono, @Email)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nome", c.Nome);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cognome", c.Cognome);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telefono1", c.Telefono1);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telefono", c.Telefono);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", c.Email);

        conn.Open();
        int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (rows > 0)
        {
            isSuccess = true;  
        }
        else
        {
            isSuccess = false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
    return isSuccess;
}
```

It doesn't give any errors, it work but when i type the ata into txtBoxes and then i press the add button it says Error (message box inserte in the else)

Comment: You're not handling exceptions in your `Insert` method - I assume there's a SQL exception being raised, but since you capture every exception but do nothing with it, you won't know that unless you actually debug.

Comment: If there was an exception it should just not work the app, i think, have you got any 
suggestion? (it's my first time with c# so I am not so fond of it)

Comment: The reason there are no errors is because the code is actively hiding them with that `catch{}`. Don't use such code. You don't need that `try/catch` either, use a `using` block to properly close the connection, ie `using(var conn = new SqlConnection(myconnstrng)){ .....}`. Returning a bool instead of allowing the exception to propagate doesn't help anyone as you'll have no idea why the code failed or what to do about it

Comment: An empty catch will always make your life harder

Comment: It will only, "just not work" in the case of an exception if you don't catch the exception. What you have done here swallows any exception and you lose vital application health informatin as the others have mentioned. If you wanted to close the connection, you can use a ```try...finally``` block leaving out the catch. This way you'll know should anything go wrong.

Comment: Thank you to all i understand a lot of new things!

Comment: Just FYI, for future reference: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers - you don't need to add "solved" to your question's title (in fact, it's normally discouraged; remember, Stack Overflow is not a forum).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 is to remove the catch-all exception handling from the Insert method. Most of the ADO.NET database classes implement [IDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable), so you just need a `using(...)` block to make sure the command is disposed automatically (which will also close and dispose the connection instance):

```
public bool Insert (rubricaClass c) 
{
    bool isSuccess = false;

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myconnstrng);

    string sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_Rubrica (Nome, Cognome, Telefono1, Telefono, Email) VALUES (@Nome, @Cognome, @Telefono1, @Telefono, @Email)";
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nome", c.Nome);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cognome", c.Cognome);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telefono1", c.Telefono1);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telefono", c.Telefono);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", c.Email);

        conn.Open();
        int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (rows > 0)
        {
            isSuccess = true;  
        }
        else
        {
            isSuccess = false;
        }
    }

    return isSuccess;
}
```

Once that's squared away, Step 2 is to move your exception handling into the application. I don't recommend this "catch everything"-style code, but it works for now, I suppose:

```
private void BntAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    //Get the value from the imput fields
    c.Nome = txtBoxName.Text;
    c.Cognome = txtBoxSurname.Text;
    c.Telefono1= txtBoxPhone1.Text;
    c.Telefono = txtBoxPhone.Text;
    c.Email = txtBoxEmail.Text;

    try
    {
        //Inserting Data into Database uing the method we created is previous episode
        bool success = c.Insert(c);
        if (success == true)
        {
            //Successfully Inserted
            MessageBox.Show("New contact added!");
            //Call the clear Method Here
            Clear();
        }
        else
        {
            //Failed to add Contact
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR!)");
        }
        //load Data on Data GRidview
        DataTable dt = c.Select();
        dgvRubrica.DataSource = dt;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

This will likely tell you that you either have an error in your SQL syntax, or that the command itself could not be run (i.e. the connection string is invalid or the server can't be reached).